# How to resolve org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available

Tags: jsp, servlets

How to resolve org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available.when i open this one  localhost:8080/manager/html it is working but click on /manager or host-manager or examples on JSP example  i am getting error like that

```
      org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:585)
       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:391)
       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
     root cause
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:228)
        org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:638)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
         org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334
```

Answer (score 2):

The file you are missing is: jasper.jar
You can find a complete list of jars in tomcat lib in the RELEASE_NOTES: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RELEASE-NOTES.txt under "Bundled APIs"

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some jasper libraries in your Tomcat lib-folder. See here http://affy.blogspot.de/2006/10/fixing-no-java-compiler-available.html

I currently have this problem with an old 5.5 installation. The file I was missing is jasper-compiler-jdt.jar.

HTH, Alex

Comment: i have used tomcat 7 in linux 12.04 . how to download and put jasper-compiler-jdt.jar in tomcat 7

Comment: I just checked the files at tomcat.apache.org. It seems as if there is no such file in Tomcat 7. Sorry, but then I am of no help for you. It solved the same issue in Tomcat 5.5 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Watch for the java/tomcat versions!

The java version of my target server was 1.7 so I added the line to the pom.xml:

`<java.version>1.7</java.version>`

It worked well with the tomcat server 1.7 configured in eclipse. Then I switched to embedded tomcat server of spring boot and got the same error. By default spring started a tomcat version 8.xx. After realized that I added:

`<tomcat.version>7.0.63</tomcat.version>`

into the pom.xml and the error disappeared. (I think only the main version of tomcat matters. )